# NMAP port scanning - inconsistent results

Tags: linux-networking, nmap

I ran the same nmap commands subsequently, and got two sets of results.

I know that there are three open ports, but on each run, only two are shown.

Can anyone explain these results?

```
ramses@deimos:~/$ nmap -p 50000-60000 some-server

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-07-11 14:00 VET
Nmap scan report for some-server (some-internet-ip)
Host is up (0.075s latency).
Not shown: 9999 filtered ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
53409/tcp open  unknown 
56475/tcp open  unknown 

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 45.94 seconds
ramses@deimos:~/$ nmap -p 50000-60000 some-server

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-07-11 14:01 VET
Nmap scan report for some-server (some-internet-ip)
Host is up (0.078s latency).
Not shown: 9999 filtered ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
53409/tcp open  unknown
54514/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 67.51 seconds
ramses@deimos:~/$ nmap -p 50000-60000 some-server

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-07-11 14:06 VET
Nmap scan report for some-server (some-internet-ip)
Host is up (0.075s latency).
Not shown: 9999 filtered ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
53409/tcp open  unknown
56475/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 64.02 seconds
ramses@deimos:~/$ nmap -p 50000-60000 some-server

Starting Nmap 6.40 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2015-07-11 14:08 VET
Nmap scan report for some-server (some-internet-ip)
Host is up (0.075s latency).
Not shown: 9999 filtered ports
PORT      STATE SERVICE
53409/tcp open  unknown
54514/tcp open  unknown

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 58.14 seconds
```

Comment: How do you know that three ports are open?  Do you control `some-server`?

Comment: what is the output of `netstat -lntu` on the server? Do you have firewall or some iptables rules? What does the nmap list when you call it on that server with localhost argument?

Comment: @MadHatter, it's an ec2 server that we use in the company; however I do not control it. The guy who has control over it is on vacations...